# Storing objects as references?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm not entirely sure if what I want is possible or not, be here's what I want:

I have a couple collection of different objects that I am storing. Let's say a collection of `Users` and a collection of `Projects`.

Here are some examples of what they might look like:

```
public class User
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }

    public List<Project> Projects { get; set;} 
}

public class Project
{
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public User Manager { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see, a User can have multiple projects, while a Project has a User.

Basically when I have these stored, I want to be able to edit a User in the collection of Users and automatically have any Projects with that User be updated to contain the updated information about that User. Subsequently, if I update a Project any Users with that Project will automatically have their Project updated. Like some way of storing references to the objects rather than values?

Is there any way of doing this?

Comment: The key word sounds like "store." What do you mean? `Project` and `User` are reference types, so the instances of `Project` in `Projects` and the `User` referred to by `Manager` already are references.

Comment: Have you tried it out to see what happens?  I think you'll observe it's already doing exactly what you want.

Comment: This would already happen.

Comment: I'm confused - in C# objects are *always* referred to by reference rather than by value, @ScottHannen is correct here. Can you clarify? is there some behavior you're expecting beyond the default reference? Also, what do you mean by "store" - do you mean "keep in memory" or "serialize to persistent storage?"

Comment: Where do you "store" the objects? In a database? On disk (using serialization)? Or?

Answer (score 3):

What you have here are object *references*. That means, as long as you are referring to the same **object** (*instance*), by default everything works as you'd expect.

Example (using your classes):

```
User u = new User();
Project p = new Project();
p.Manager = u;
u.Projects.Add(p);
```

This creates an empty user and an empty project. The project references the user, the user's project list references the project.

Now you change the name of the user and the project:

```
u.FirstName = "Test";
u.LastName = "User";
```

This will allow you to get the following result:

```
Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", p.Manager.FirstName, p.Manager.LastName);
=> Test User
```

Another thing you can do now is this:

```
User userInfo = p.Manager;
userInfo.EMailAddress = "test@company.org";
```

This will reflect whatever way you access the user object you've assigned, as all these "variables" are "pointing" to the same object instance (they reference the same object in memory).

You can even pass your object reference to another method:

```
public void ChangeProjectManagerEmail(Project theProject, string newEMail)
{
    theProject.Manager.EMailAddress = newEMail;
}
```

Calling the above method like this:

```
ChangeProjectManagerEmail(p, "hello@world.com");
```

Will result in this:

```
Console.WriteLine(u.EMailAddress);
=> hello@world.com
```

What **does not work is this**:

```
User anotherUser = new User();
anotherUser.UserId = 5;

Console.WriteLine(p.Manager.UserId);
```

This will output `0`, as the new user `anotherUser` is not referenced by any other object.

You do need to be careful when it comes to persisting such a structure. While storing it (in a file, a database, etc.) is pretty easy, you need to make sure that you re-create the exact same object structure when *reading* the data. Imagine this:

- Project 1 references User u1
- Project 2 references User u1
- u1 references Project 1 and 2

Now first of all you need to decide whether you want to persist per user or per project, otherwise you might do duplicate work. When *restoring* the persisted information you need to make sure that you create *only one user*! (it's best to use the unique ID to check whether the user has already been restored). Otherwise you'll end up with two distinct `User` objects with the same information and you will wonder why changing the user only reflects for one project. The worst case would be that after changing the user information you'll end up with two users with the same ID but different information in your storage.

---

All that said: **WATCH OUT**! Your object structure is somewhat dangerous in terms of cross-references. As it is now, it is very well possible to add a project to a user which references a totally different user as its manager. Example:

```
User user1 = new User();
// Initialize ID, name, etc.

User user2 = new User();
// Initialize ID, name, etc.

Project p = new Project();
// Initialize stuff
p.Manager = user2;

user1.Projects.Add(p);
```

See the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the Observer Design Pattern to notify the 'observers' when a particular object changes.

*"The observer design pattern requires a division between an observer, Which registers for notifications, and the provider, Which monitors data and sends notifications to one or more observers."*

See the implementation of this Pattern in Dot Net:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff506346(v=vs.110).aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee817669.aspx

If you want that only the database level, you can create a trigger "ON UPDATE" to make the desired changes.

Comment: I'm not sure whether that helps, because I guess the basic knowledge about object references is missing here.

Comment: Okay @Thorsten Dittmar, that's true ... Anyway, he and all people who access may acquire knowledge ...

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you just keep the user id in the project and when you require to know who the project belongs to just run a `select` like `users.select(x => x.userid == project.userid)`

Comment: And why not keep a list of projects for each user?

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar Well he is doing this. or are you sarcastic? i don't understand

Comment: No, I'm not being sarcastic. I just slightly misread your answer :-) I wanted to say that it would be best to decide whether you want each project to reference the user it belongs to **or** have each user keep a list of all projects he owns, but not both, as this can lead to problems (see my answer, at the bottom). My comment aimed towards saying that either solution has more overhead if you want to determine the other component.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar i agree with what you said. There can surely be a circle reference in OP's code, but if he tends to use it this way and only keeps the userId the circle reference would be stoped and it would still be easy to use linq on single projects/users or groups there of if it is done this way